# Does the shell run commands before pipe in a subshell?

Tags: shell

```
x=0; { x=1; echo $x; } | cat; echo $x
```

prints

```
1
0
```

while I expected

```
1
1.
```

Why? At last, curly brackets create no subshell.

I tested with bash and busybox sh (ash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash **both** sides of a pipeline are run in subshells (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines) unless you `shopt -s lastpipe; set +m`, where the *last* command in a pipe is executed in the current shell

```
$ sum=0; seq 10 | while read n; do ((sum+=n)); done; echo $sum
0
$ shopt -s lastpipe
$ sum=0; seq 10 | while read n; do ((sum+=n)); done; echo $sum
0
$ set +m
$ sum=0; seq 10 | while read n; do ((sum+=n)); done; echo $sum
55
```

In your example, the first command in the pipeline will *always* be run in a subshell.

I can't speak for `ash`